# Rspec: why can you pass a test double to your application code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm reading up on [*rspec-mocks*](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks) and got a little confused with Message Expectations.

> A message expectation is an expectation that the test double will
>   receive a message some time before the example ends. If the message is
>   received, the expectation is satisfied. If not, the example fails.
>
> ```
> validator = double("validator")
> validator.should_receive(:validate).with("02134")
> zipcode = Zipcode.new("02134", validator)
> zipcode.valid?
> ```

So my understanding is you create a dummy object and specify it should "receive" a message (which is this [validate](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/EachValidator.html#method-i-validate) from ActiveModel) with argument `02134`. If it did at some point then this test will pass.

My question is:

1. Why can you pass `validator` to `Zipcode.new`? Is your application code supposed to expect to take in an extra argument (test double)?
2. What does "receive a message" mean exactly for a test double? Does it mean it will be called by the message (in this case the `validate` method)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no types in  Ruby so yo can send any object to any method. This answers your `1`

For your `2`:

Doubles are great because to test an isolated method, you actually don't need a full object.

`should_receive(:foo)` means:

- you expect your double to receive the `foo` method (`your_double.foo` somewhere)
- `foo` will not be called, but it can return the result you want (use `and_return`) to proceed with your specs.

Comment: there is no rule, it depends on it's `initialize` emthod

Comment: So in order to use Doubles, you need to modify the `initialize` method signature in your app code? ('cause I used the plain Rspec before and I didn't need to change any of my code)